# Force Creation of New Node With hook_feeds_presave Rather Than Node Update

Tags: feeds

I want to have very specific control over the node update process for Feeds. Using `hook_feeds_presave()` I can stop a node from being updated with `$entity->feeds_item->skip = TRUE;` but how can I force a new node to be created.

If a node would otherwise update an existing node I want it to create a new node.

This is for Drupal 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Entity::isNew](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AisNew/8.2.x) function to check if the entity is new, and skip the setting of skip to true:

```
  if(!$entity::isNew()){
    $entity->feeds_item->skip = TRUE;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I am trying to do is force a new node to be created if it would otherwise be a duplicate. So another words make it is_new.

Comment: if i understand, you want to create cloned node in update of node, for instance  on update of node with nid = `2` it will create node with nid = `3` .?

Comment: Not exactly.  Let's say I have it set that it updates nodes that match on ID in the Feeds UI.  This would mean it would find nid = X and update that nid rather than creating a new node.  I would like to interrupt this process and force a new node to be created rather than node X being updated.